# ldap_get_option returing -1 in C++ Linux

Tags: c++, openssl, ldap, openldap, ldap-query

I am new to ldap. I need to get TLS library context using LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CTX option. But ldap_get_option returning me -1. The API looks like this,

```
SSL_CTX *SSLCtx = NULL;
ldap_get_option(0,LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CTX,static_cast<void*>(SSLCtx));
```

Here ldap_get_options returns me -1. 
Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: First param shouldn't be a zero. It should be a pointer to your ldap's context.

Comment: If you are using tls communication, then `ldap_start_tls`, `ldap_install_tls` should have been called before calling this get for `LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CTX`